# Silverlight UserControl Resources are ambiguous?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik, radgrid

I'm relatively new to Silverlight/Telerik, how would I pass the resources it is looking for from the newly added "LayoutRoot" Grid to the "UserControl.Resources" that was originally top level.

Thank you,
I appreciate any help in advance :)

```
<controls:ViewBase x:Class="CS.MyProgram.Silverlight.Module.Viewer.LoanTradingPnLDashboard.LoanTradingPnLViewer"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:CS.MyProgram.Library.Controls.Data;assembly=Library.Controls" 
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CS.MyProgram.Silverlight.Library.Controls;assembly=Library"
xmlns:libraryData="clr-namespace:CS.MyProgram.Library.Controls.Data;assembly=Library.Controls"
xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView" 
xmlns:telerikControl="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation"
xmlns:navigate="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" 
xmlns:Controls1="clr-namespace:CS.MyProgram.Library.Controls;assembly=Library.Controls" 
xmlns:Controls2="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input" 
xmlns:asp="clr-namespace:System.Reflection.Emit;assembly=mscorlib" 
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:CS.MyProgram.Silverlight.Module.Viewer.LoanTradingDashboard.Converters;assembly=Viewer" 
xmlns:GenericComponents="clr-namespace:CS.MyProgram.Silverlight.ComponentLibraries.GenericComponents;assembly=GenericComponents" 
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:CS.MyProgram.Silverlight.ComponentLibraries.GenericComponents.Command;assembly=GenericComponents"
xmlns:vcharting="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=SLVisifire.Charts"
xmlns:telerikGridView="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <UserControl.Resources> <!-- !!!!!! This Line Has The Ambiguous Reference -->
        <!--STUFF LIKE THIS-->
        <telerikControl:Office_BlackTheme x:Key="Theme"/>
        <telerikControl:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <!--STUFF LIKE THIS-->
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="AnotherGrid" >
        <!--STUFF LIKE THIS-->
        <telerik:CustomDataGrid />
        <!--STUFF LIKE THIS-->
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce any 'Ambiguous Reference' error.  The error I get with your XAML is the following:

> The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'UserControl'.

An element with name `<Something.SomethingElse>` can mean an attached property of name `SomethingElse` that belongs to the class `Something` (for example, `Grid.Row`) or it can refer to the (non-attached) `SomethingElse` dependency property of the `Something` class, *provided this element is a direct child of a* `<Something>` *element*.

In this case, because `<UserControl.Resources>` element isn't as a direct child of a `<UserControl>` element (it's a direct child of a `<Grid>`), Silverlight looks for an attached property named `Resources` on the `UserControl` type, but no such attached property exists.

The fix to this is quite simple: change `UserControl.Resources` to `Grid.Resources`:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!--STUFF LIKE THIS-->
        <telerikControl:Office_BlackTheme x:Key="Theme"/>
        <telerikControl:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <!--STUFF LIKE THIS-->
    </Grid.Resources>
```

The `Resources` property is inherited, by `Grid`, `UserControl` and numerous other types, from [`FrameworkElement.Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources(v=vs.95).aspx), so it doesn't just belong to `UserControl`s.  You can in fact put it under the top-level `<controls:ViewBase>` element, if you wish.  If you do, you must name it `<controls:ViewBase.Resources>`, as it is then a direct child of a `<controls:ViewBase>` element.

Comment: 'Ambiguous Reference' is shown by IntelliSense in xaml editor in tooltip.

Comment: @noaRAVE: that might be something to do with the Telerik control library, which I don't have a copy of.  I still can't reproduce that message, but thanks for taking the time to explain how you were seeing it.